# New Openstack Autopilot stuck at: In progress - Configure availability zones - 98%

Tags: juju, openstack, lxc, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I see in landscape0:job-handler-1.log:

```
2015-03-18 14:00:13 INFO root RetryingCall for '_create_networks_and_router' failed, trying 119 more time(s):
2015-03-18 14:00:13 INFO root Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError'>: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.

2015-03-18 14:00:13 INFO twisted Stopping factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x7f671863a128>
2015-03-18 14:00:13 INFO root RetryingCall for 'get_client' failed, trying 119 more time(s):
2015-03-18 14:00:13 INFO root Traceback: <class 'canonical.openstack.clientshelper.ServiceNotFound'>: The compute service couldn't be found in the Keystone service catalog.
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:423:errback
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:490:_startRunCallbacks
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:577:_runCallbacks
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:1155:gotResult
--- <exception caught here> ---
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:1097:_inlineCallbacks
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py:389:throwExceptionIntoGenerator
/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/openstack/clientshelper.py:56:get_client
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:1099:_inlineCallbacks
/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/openstack/clientshelper.py:81:_get_authenticated_endpoint


15-03-18 14:04:43 INFO root RetryingCall for '_create_networks_and_router' failed, trying 110 more time(s):
2015-03-18 14:04:43 INFO root Traceback: <class 'canonical.landscape.model.openstack.jobs.NeutronDHCPAgentNotUp'>: No DHCP agent found.
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:423:errback
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:490:_startRunCallbacks
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:577:_runCallbacks
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:1155:gotResult
--- <exception caught here> ---
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:1097:_inlineCallbacks
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py:389:throwExceptionIntoGenerator
/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/openstack/jobs.py:496:_create_networks_and_router
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:1099:_inlineCallbacks
/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/openstack/jobs.py:557:_check_dhcp_agent_up
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

---

Re ran the deployment and it completed fully this time.

The openstack-install seems a bit brittle. Having issues with single system install on my workstation but multi works after two attempts thankfully.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how long it has been stuck.

These backtraces are normal during the deployment: it's trying to configure services that aren't ready yet, that's why it retries so many times. Juju is still deploying them, creating relations, etc.

Depending on your hardware and network bandwidth, an autopilot run could take 40 minutes or even more. Has it given up yet?

Comment: Been several hours - it still said 'In Progress'. I just tore down the cluster and restarted but seeing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I re-ran the Landscape Autopilot step and the install completed successfully this time.